# Converting Multi-Dimensional Array to Single, with nullable Values

Tags: c#, excel, excel-dna

I am using ExcelDNA/C#/Excel primarily. What I am essentially trying to do is convert a multi-dimensional array (namely a range of cells) to a singular dimensional array, using the following code:

```
private static string[] MultiToSingle(object[,] multiArray)
{
   List<string> tempList;
   string[] returnArray;
   tempList = new List<string>();

   //Add each element of the multi-dimensional Array to the list
   foreach (object oneObj in multiArray)
   {
      tempList.Add(oneObj.ToString());
   }
   //Convert the list to a single dimensional array
   returnArray = tempList.ToArray();
   return returnArray;
}
```

This works a treat, and is used a number of times throughout my project, however I would like to add some more functionality.

When I try to run this function with a range that contains an empty cell, it errors horribly, at the moment I just have a try/catch with an error message informing the user to enter N/A into any empty cells.

What I'd really like to do, is in this function perhaps, convert any 'null' or whatever Excel stores empty cells as to the text string "N/A".

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Perhaps just:

```
tempList.Add(oneObj == null ? "n/a" : oneObj.ToString());
```

I can also think of ways to make it more efficient, if you want:

```
string[] arr = new string[multiArray.Length];
int i = 0;
foreach (object oneObj in multiArray)
{
    arr[i++] = oneObj == null ? "n/a" : oneObj.ToString();
}
return arr;
```

This cuts out the intermediate list and a few backing array copies.

Comment: I'm no C# guru, but what would `(oneObj as string)` do? Wouldn't it try to infer the explicit cast to string by using the `ToString()` method if `oneObj` is not **NULL**?

Comment: @flindeberg no, it wouldn't. If it **is** a string, it will return the string. If it **isn't** a string, it will always be null. No `.ToString()` etc will be called. So `123` will become `null`.

Comment: Thanks for this Marc, didn't get a chance to reply yesterday but this answer is exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 2):

If you're finding nulls, which is probably why you're getting an error, Marc's answer is right. But you might like to use the function in another context - directly as a worksheet function exposed by Excel-DNA.

Excel-DNA marshals empty Excel cells into the argument array as objects of type ExcelDna.Integration.ExcelEmpty. So if your code is called directly from Excel-DNA as a worksheet function, you'd get the type name from the ToString(), and not an error.

So your function with the return type changed to object[] (Excel-DNA won't register your string[] function directly) looks like this:

```
public static object[] MultiToSingle(object[,] multiArray)
{
   List<string> tempList;
   object[] returnArray;
   tempList = new List<string>();

   //Add each element of the multi-dimensional Array to the list
   foreach (object oneObj in multiArray)
   {
      tempList.Add(oneObj.ToString());
   }
   //Convert the list to a single dimensional array
   returnArray = tempList.ToArray();
   return returnArray;
}
```

and gives this output in Excel when called directly as a worksheet function:
[image: Excel-DNA array function]

For this case you could add a check on the type of the array item to deal with empty cells:

```
 tempList.Add( oneObj is ExcelEmpty ? "!EMPTY" : oneObj.ToString() );
```

Comment: Much appreciated Govert! Unfortunately that option isn't open to me though, Marc's solution worked a treat.

Answer (score 0):

```
tempList.Add( oneObj.Value == null ? "!EMPTY" : oneObj.ToString() );
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](//s.tk/meta/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post.